# Issue with using int.parse() in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm currently teaching myself the Dart language, and my first app doesn't seem to be working right.  Here's the code that's causing trouble:

```dart
usrLoc = int.parse(query("#txtLoc").text);
```

When I try to run the app, it opens fine, but when I click the button that triggers this (and three other similar parses), the debugger stops and tells me "Source not found" for `int._native_parse()`, `int._parse()`, and `int.parse()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` property for the specified element `#txtLoc` returns an empty string.

The [`parse`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html#parse) method requires that:

> The `source` must be a non-empty sequence of base- radix digits, optionally prefixed with a minus or plus sign ('-' or '+').

You can [specify an `onError` named argument](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html#parse) in your call to `parse`, which takes a callback that handles the invalid input. E.g., if you want the `parse` call to return the value `42` for all invalid input, you can do this:

```dart
usrLoc = int.parse(query("#txtLoc").text, onError: (val) => 42);
```

If you really expect the element to have some text, you can store the result of `query("#txtLoc").text` into a separate variable and verify the value. It would also be interesting to check what the real element type is or which tag is marked with id `#txtLoc`.

If you want to get the content of an input element, you should use the `value` property instead of `text`:

```dart
query("#txtLoc").value
```

Comment: Sorry, in my sleep-deprived state it appears I forgot a few details.  `#txtLoc` is an HTML input tag that takes in a zip code and I'm trying to place it in the variable `usrLoc` for future usage.

Would there be an easier way to get data from an input box?  I'm rather new to web programming, so I'm really learning as I go along.  Thanks.

Comment: I know how it feels, I am a backend guy and I also need to check the docs for these things :) You should use `value` instead of `text`, but you still need to provide error handler if the input can be empty. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Zdeslav.  I've never been great at reading through books or tutorials, so I was trying to make this work by looking over the example projects that came with the editor, which is where `.text` came from.  Usually Googling about an issue works well for the established languages I've learned in the past, but it looks like using a newer language like Dart will require a bit more community involvement.

Comment: The `onError()` callback does not receive an error parameter, it receives the source string. Using the variable `e` is confusing here for that reason.

Comment: you are right, it is a bit misleading - I have changed `e` -> `val`